# resizing an image only if upload_to was called django

Tags: python, django, save, image-uploading

I have the following code, models.py:

```
class Location(models.Model):
         image_file = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_location, null=True, blank=True)
         name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

which calls the `upload_to` function where the image is being renamed. Then my save method

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            this = Location.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if this.image_file:
                os.remove(this.image_file.path)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass
        super(Location, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        try:
            this = Location.objects.get(id=self.id)
            if this.image_file:
                resize(this.image_file.path)
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            pass

def upload_to_location(instance, filename):
    blocks = filename.split('.')
    ext = blocks[-1]
    filename = "%s.%s" % (instance.name.replace(" ", "-"), ext)
    return filename
```

checks if a previously uploaded file exists and if so, it deletes it. And then after is being saved, it checks again if the file exists and then calls the `resize` function. That works, if I upload a file and click save. However, if I only change the name of the Location, the `os.remove` function is called, deletes my file and then the `resize` function trhows an error. 
Therefore I only want to call the `os.remove` function when the user uploads a `upload_to` will be called.

So I tried a couple of things but couldn't get it done. I also tried `pre_save` and `post_save` signales. Hereby, I had a problem of getting the path of the image:

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=Company)
def my_function2(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print instance.path   #didn't work
    print os.path.realpath(instance) #didn't work
```

Does anyone know how I could solve this either with `pre_save` or something else?

Comment: Have you read/considered implementing a [custom upload handler](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/files/uploads/#custom-upload-handlers) to fit your needs? Another possible hint on how to do it [here](https://github.com/django-ckeditor/django-ckeditor/issues/130)

Comment: Have you written a custom function for `upload_to` parameter?

Comment: yes, I did, I updated my question, so in the `upload_to_location` the name will be changed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to call `os.remove` only when `upload_to` is invoked, why not move that code inside `upload_to_location` function?

```
def upload_to_location(self, filename):
    try:
        this = Location.objects.get(id=self.id)
        if this.image_file:
            os.remove(this.image_file.path)
    except ObjectDoesNotExist:
        pass
    # do something else...
```

This way, when `upload_to` is called, `os.remove` will be called.

**Extras**

Instead of calling `os.remove` to delete associated file, you can delete the file by calling that file field's `delete()` method.

```
if this.image_file:
    this.image_file.delete(save=True)
```

`save=True` saves the `this` instance after deleting the file. If you don't want that, pass `save=False`. Default is `True`.

And in the function `my_function2` where you're listening to signals, it should be:

```
instance.image_file.path
```

Comment: works ! all of them! Thank you so much, especially for the detailed answer!